# Hamburger Menù BootStrap

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar for desktop view and hamburger menu for mobile,I have one problem about the hamburger menu; The bar of the hamburger menu cover part of the background image, I want that the background image go always after the hamburger menu. This is my code

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="col-interno">  <--col interno is for color-->
      <!-- Logo -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a href="#" style="vertical-align:middle" class="navbar-left"><img src="css/logo.png" style="width:78px"></a>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Generic Brand</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Menu Items -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="chi-siamo.html">Who</a></li>
              <li><a href="servizi.html">Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="contatti.html">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
     <div id="testata-back">
     </div>
      </nav>
       <div class="testata-500-1 testata-servizi"> 
        <div class="testata-500-logo-transparent">
<!-- Those classes are two image that i want on the bottom of the hamburger menu-->

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYoXS.png)

CSS

```
 testata-500-1{margin:0 auto;height:500px;box-shadow:inset 0 -2px 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4)}
```

CSS of div

```
@media only screen and (min-width:1024px){.testata,.contents,#footer-bar,#credits-bar{width:960px}#hamburger{display:none}}@media only screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1023px){.testata,.contents,#footer-bar,#credits-bar{width:740px}#logo{position:absolute;left:26px;top:65px;z-index:2000;width:150px;height:124px}.testata-500-1{height:250px;background-size:130%}.testata-500-logo-transparent{height:250px;background-size:155%}#testata-menu{top:10px}#hamburger{display:none}}
```

Comment: can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I've added a screenshot right now!

Comment: Could you show your css that describes the div background properties?
 Also, have you tried `background-size: cover`?

Comment: now i try with background-sire: cover .. i have never tried this one, now i've posted the css about the image

Answer (score 0):

You can position your background image using the `background-position: X Y` to your background image CSS. Keep the value of `X` to 0. And adjust the y axis to your desired height.
Use media screen if necessary.

Comment: i've tried now with background-position in the CSS document, but nothing is happen

Comment: Are you building this out local or is it on a server? If on a server can you provide the website name. I don't see why it wouldn't be working so I would need to take a look at the full code.